# Using apt-cache to search for packages that include a specific program?

Tags: debian, apt

Is it possible to use `apt-cache` (or more generally APT) to search for packages that include a specific program, like `setcap` or `ifconfig`?

I know i can use `dpkg -S <prog>` to identify installed packages that include `<prog>`, but is it possible to retrieve such information from remote package repositories?

Comment: Does the highest voted answer on https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/149805 answer your question?

Comment: @Quasímodo - I don't think so. That answers how to find packages that depend on a specific package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `apt-file` for this task. If it's not installed, `sudo apt install apt-file`. Run `apt-file update` after installation.

`apt-file search setcap` for example.

If you don't want to install anything locally, you can use [debian index](https://packages.debian.org/index) online.